# Running scala code using java -jar <jarfile>

Tags: scala, hadoop2

I am trying to run scala code using java -jar <> i am getting below issue 
ERROR:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream at com.cargill.finance.cdp.blackline.Ingest.main(Ingest.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream

The same code is running fine with spark-submit.

I am trying to write data to hdfs file.

I have imported below classes

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream

Answer (score 3):

You need to add *all* dependencies (including transitive dependencies, i.e. dependencies of dependencies) to `-cp` argument. If you just look at [direct dependencies of hadoop-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1) you'll see why you should never do this manually. Instead use a build system. If you followed e.g. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html it actually sets up [SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running-Project-Code.html), so you can do [`sbt run`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running-Project-Code.html) to run the main class like `java -cp <lots of libraries> -jar <jarfile>` would). If you didn't, add `build.sbt` as described there.